# why does my express route work for "/" but not "/:id"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

I was troubleshooting why my route wasn't working and i came across this.

In my ./routes/jobs.js,

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Job.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, job) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.json({ msg: "job deleted"});
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

When i tested on postman, Delete - `http://localhost:5000/dashboard/60b9405e1ea`

Would return the id only `60b9405e1ea` and not delete the db job.

I changed my route to "/" and tested it out. using `http://localhost:5000/dashboard` in postman.

```
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  Job.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, job) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.json({ msg: "job deleted"});
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

It executed the delete request with `{msg: "job deleted"}`. (Obviously didnt delete db job since no id was given).

Keep in mind in my server.js im using,

```
app.use("/dashboard", require("./routes/jobs"));
```

Any help would be appreciated on why /:id is not being executed

Comment: You're going to have to give us a bigger picture of how your routes are initialized.  What you show above does not indicate an obvious problem so there must be something wrong in other code that is affecting it such as other route definitions, other middleware, etc...

Comment: please include a picture of the delete request on postman and its response

Comment: @elbraulio [postman result](https://i.imgur.com/8ImAo7k.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting the id in the console, it's the problem with the query you make.
Try any of these,

```js
Model.remove({ _id: req.body.id }, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        message.type = 'notification!';
    }
    else {
        message.type = 'error';
    }
});
```

or

```js
Model.findOneAndRemove({id: req.params.id}, function(err){
});
```

or a traditional approach:

```js
Model.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    }

    doc.remove(callback); //Removes the document
})
```